# Confusion regarding ISD and IWD

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

> Statement-1: If a game is ISD-solvable(Iterated strict dominance), then the
> security level of every player is the same as his utility in the ISD
> solution.
>
> Statement-2:IWD(Iterated weak dominance) is order-dependent in 2x2 games.

## Attempt:..

I believe the first answer is false(because though we have assumed that the players are rational, it might be possible if opponent deviates from "being rational", the utility would be lower for me) and so is the second answer-  false(Because in 2x2 case there is no other options to arrive at different ordering by selecting any other rows or columns).

Please let me know whether I am right or wrong.